# Postgresql Query - Average time from datetime field in Posgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, average

I have an SQL table:

```
Id | EntryTime | Duration
```

And I want to find the average entry TIME OF DAY between two hours, taking into account all records between those hours.

so if my EntryTime field between my hours:

```
(Edited)
12:00:00
10:00:00
08:00:00
10:00:00
```

Then the average time returned should just be:

```
10:00:00
```

The date should not be taken into account at all, and it should be returned in string format, or a manner which returns ONLY `10:00:00`.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please review the help topic [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer.  In particular post table definitions (actual DDL or at least column type definitions).  Also, please explain how you arrive at the expected result of 10:00:00 as average of the given EntryTime columns. Also what would the result be for an additional set. For example adding the 2hour range 17:00:00 - 19:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, you can use intervals for this; the idea is to substract the date part from the timestamp: this gives you an interval that represents the time portion, than you can then average.

Assuming that your table is called `t` and that the timestamps are stored in column `ts`, that would be:

```
select avg(entry_time - entry_time::date) avg_time from t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=95b47bc3e94412d951124f95a187587d)**

Sample data:

```
| entry_time          |
| :------------------ |
| 2020-07-14 12:00:00 |
| 2020-07-12 10:00:00 |
| 2020-07-10 08:00:00 |
| 2020-07-01 10:00:00 |
```

Results:

```
| avg_time |
| :------- |
| 10:00:00 |
```

Comment: Do you know this?
[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=681301097908283943d12ac28e30502d)
The output is : ```09:04:19.3```

I want this output 
```09:04:19```

Answer (score 0):

Try SELECT avg(entry_time - entry_time::date)**::time(0)** to avoid seconds fraction.